# Regex pattern anywhere in another pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find a pattern that can have another fixed pattern anywhere in it.

Example :

```
Looking for pattern: "HERE"    
This pattern can also have one or multiple times the pattern "##" in it.
```

Following entries should match :

```
"A match is expected HE##RE"    
"... also H##ER##E ..."    
"... and the basic one HERE  ..."
```

I tried to make a pre-computing thing to remove these unwanted "##", but this is not acceptable as some information can be lost like in this example :

```
"This is important ##and the match is only HER##E"
```

I also thought about indexing all ## before pre-filtering computation and then rebuild averything with indexes but I don't think it is an optimal solution.

Does anyone have some regex tips or an idea about that ?
Thank you all.

Comment: Could you share some code of what you've done so far?

Comment: Not really. I am facing this problem but as I didn't find any suitable solution I haven't code it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of optional groups `(?:##)?` and use word boundaries `\b` to prevent the match being part of a larger word:

```
\bH(?:##)?E(?:##)?R(?:##)?E\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xVTlZX/1)

An option to make it dynamically might be to use split and join:

```js
let d = "(?:##)?";
let word = "\\b" + "HERE".split('').join(d) + "\\b";
let str = "A match is expected HE##RE";
let pattern = new RegExp(word, 'gi');
console.log(pattern);
console.log(str.match(pattern));
```

Comment: `(?:##)?` the optional groups wont be included in the match right ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee They are part of the match if the `##` is present. But it will also match if the `##` is not present. https://regex101.com/r/OOJob8/2

Comment: Yes that can work. Is there a way to do this dynamically ?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically?

Comment: In my case, the "HERE" is dynamic and can be quite long. The "##" is also dynamic and is multiple (##|other|dependingOnContext). I will accept your answer as it can work, but if the final regex can be 10 char long instead of 500 that would be perfect ;)    

So the question is: Is there a way write all the (?:##)? in a shorter way ?

Comment: @07Select I have added an example how you might make it dynamic. I don't think you can write the non capturing group in a shorter way.

Comment: Ok that answer my last unwritten question. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be pretty complicated; assuming that we'd be looking for words (with orders) with extra chars, such as #, I'm guessing that maybe this expression

```
(?=.*(?<=\s|^)(H\S*E\S*R\S*E)(?=\s|$)).*
```

might be a start, which would fail in such instances:

```
Anything before then #HERE
Anything before then HERE#
```

if those would be desired.

#### [DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/MrwCBx/1/)

We can simplify it to:

```
(?=.*(H\S*E\S*R\S*E)).*
```

yet this would pass anything, not just words.

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/Y6fmP1/1/)

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/MrwCBx/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I cannot accept your solution as the following pattern will match "HEERE". It shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

```js
let s = `A match is expected HE##RE
... also H##ER##E ...    
"... and the basic one HERE  ...`;

console.log(s.match(/\bH#*E#*R#*E\b/g))
```

Comment: Thank you Bluehipy. Your solution can also work, but I got the same non-bloquing problem with it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57097027/regex-pattern-anywhere-in-another-pattern#comment100715948_57097125

Comment: You can add the \b\b to restrict on wird match other than that I don't get the non-blobking issue :)\

Comment: Still not acceptable as it don't work for all languages. Broken example with french/spanich : wordéHERE.    
Answer by The four bird is ok ;)